# Get specific text into a pandas dataframe, webscraping with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm really struggling with extracting some data points from a webpage into a pandas dataframe.

I'm interesting to extract the values `38.31` and `-0.06`.

If I'm using `name_y = soup.find(id='current')` I get the following result:

```
<div id="current">
<b>Current<span class="currentTitle">
S&amp;P 500 PE Ratio</span>:</b>
38.31


<span class="neg">

-0.06
(-0.16%)

</span>
<div id="timestamp">


10:39 AM EST, Fri Mar 5

</div>
</div>
```

I have tried `name_y = soup.find(id='current').text` and `name_y = soup.find(id='current').b.next_sibling` but it still give me some noise.

**Current result:**

```
0    \n38.37\n\n\n\n\n\n
dtype: object
```

**Expected end result**:

```
print(df)
      PE         Change
0     38.31      -0.06
```

**Full code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.multpl.com/s-p-500-pe-ratio'

res = requests.get(url)
html = res.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser' )

# name_y = soup.find(id='current')

df = pd.Series(soup.find(id='current').b.next_sibling)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.strip()` to remove `\n` characters.

```
soup.find(id='current').b.next_sibling.strip()
```

Full code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.multpl.com/s-p-500-pe-ratio'

res = requests.get(url)
html = res.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

change = soup.find(id='current').select_one('.pos, .neg').get_text().split("(")[0].strip()
pe = soup.find(id='current').b.next_sibling.strip()

df = pd.DataFrame([({'PE': pe, 'Change': change})])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      PE Change
0  38.11  -0.26
```

Comment: Thanks for an excellent and clear answer, much appreciated :)!!

Comment: Okey, this is really impressive, and extra thanks @QHarr! You have helped me so much many times before really appreciate it. My dirty solution was to do a try/except statement, but this is way cleaner and better :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if this code works:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests

url = 'https://www.multpl.com/s-p-500-pe-ratio'

res = requests.get(url)
html = res.text

c=soup(html, "html.parser")
name_y = c.find(id='current')
x = name_y.text
y = name_y.find("span", {"class":"neg"})
print(x.split()[5])
print(y.text.strip().split()[0])
```

**Output**

```
38.09
-0.27
```